# Cannot add a new app to fabric

Tags: google-fabric

I am unable to add a new iOS app to fabric by following the instructions of the Fabric macOS plug in.

I have followed all of the instructions found at [Crashlytics documentation](https://www.fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install)

When running the app, I receive this error:

```
2018-03-12 14:22:24.090838-0400 [19139:8550117] [Crashlytics] Version 3.10.1 (129)
2018-03-12 14:22:24.636050-0400 [19139:8550293] [Fabric] unable to complete application configure: Error Domain=FABNetworkError Code=-5 "(null)" UserInfo={status_code=422, type=2, request_id=fbc432572e6f0e10f21d2ddc24c7f272, content_type=text/html; charset=utf-8}
```

I have tried searching StackOverflow and following answers, but no luck avoiding this error message.

Any ideas on this error message?

Comment: Mike from Firebase and Fabric here. This usually means that the app is in a partially configured state, what's the bundle id or package name of our app?

Comment: @MikeBonnell, I'm having the same issue with a whole bunch of apps on one organization.

Comment: Probably best to email support(at)fabric(dot)io with the bundle ids/package names and organization so we can better assist.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and discovered that my 'visible' (in Xcode) info.plist was not a file in my root directory, and was an out of date version from earlier development activity. I am not sure why my correct/current info.plist did not display in Xcode. I found the current info.plist in Finder (it was in the root directory in Finder, just not appearing in Xcode). I dragged the file from Finder to Xcode and accepted all the defaults in the dialog that appeared. Then I simply built and ran the current scheme and all worked as it should.
Note: It appears that for some time I have been updating the 'invisible' info.plist directly from my apps Target / Info tab.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include all dependency then throw a force crash or runtime error and do not forget to turn on your data or internet connection.